# bash compound commands with pipes

Tags: linux, bash

How explicitly point to bash what is the priority of command 
for example

> screen -dm -S test tar zxvf /tmp | gunzip

I suppose that *screen* relates to all command

> tar zxvf /tmp | gunzip

but bash doesn't know it. 
Bash divides it into

> screen -dm -S test tar zxvf /tmp

and

> gunzip

How to cause Bash to run entire command in screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have `screen` run a shell, and have the shell run your pipeline.

```
screen -dm -S test bash -c "tar zxvf /tmp | gunzip"
```